# Why this data member is initialized?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, initialization, default-constructor

I'm doing some testing...
Firstly I post my source code

the .h file

```
class Complex{
    private:
        int r = 0;//initializer
        int i ; 
    public:
        Complex(int , int I = 0);
        Complex();
        void print();
        void set(int, int I = 1);
        static void print_count();
        static int count;
};
```

the .cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "complex.h"

int Complex::count = 1;

Complex::Complex(int R , int I){
    r = R;
    i = I;

    count++;

    std::cout << "constructing Complex object...count is " << Complex::count << std::endl;
}

Complex::Complex(){//default constructor
    std::cout << "default constructor is called..." << std::endl;
}

void Complex::print(){
    std::cout << "r = " << r << ';' << "i = " << i << std::endl;
    return;
}

void Complex::set(int R, int I /*= 2*/){//will be "redefaulting", an error
    r = R;
    i = I;
    return;
}

void Complex::print_count(){//static
    Complex::count = -1;//jsut for signaling...

    std::cout << "count is " << count << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

the main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include "complex.h"

int main(){
    Complex d;//using default constructor
    d.print();

    /*Complex c(4, 5);*/
    Complex c(4);
    //c.print();

    /*c.set(2, 3)*/
    c.print();
    c.set(2 );
    c.print();

    std::cout << "count is " << c.count << std::endl;//c can access member data
    c.print_count();
    c.count++;//

    return 0;
}
```

consider the Complex object d constructed with default ctor

because the data member r is initialized using with 0, when executing d.print(),
r is expected to be 0

and i isn't, so I expected it to be garbage value

but when I'm testing, one strange thing happens.

if I eliminate this and the following lines of code in the main file:

std::cout << "count is " << c.count << std::endl;//c can access member data

then d.print() will give the value of i as 32767 on my system, which I guess it's a garbage value;

but once that line is added, d.print() just give i's value to 0 on my system.

I don't get it. I hasn't set, modiify or initialize i's value, why should it be 0?

or, it is also a garbage value?

or, calling one of those function corrupts the value of i?

how is the thing run behind the scene here?

thx for helping.

Answer (score 2):

0 is just as garbage value as any other. Don't make the mistake of thinking otherwise.

Formally, reading an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior, so there's no point in wondering about it: just fix it by initializing the variable properly.

Comment: I'm a beginner of c++
spending a little time testing these is not bad
good to see some one doing the same thing and people explaining that